# How to use PHPUnit with TestCaseTrait

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am newbie in unit testing. I read [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html) and try to do the same.

First of all, I have next environment:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2017 09:16:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

$ cat composer.json 
...
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "^3.0"
},
...
```

I have /src, /tests and /vendor directories. Composer autoloader works perfect.

My PHP-project is tightly coupled with MySQL database and all I want is unit test these functionality.

```
$ cat tests/phpunit.xml 
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <ini name="display_errors" value="On" />
        <ini name="display_startup_errors" value="On" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

And the test:

```
$ cat tests/SimpleTest.php 
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait;

require_once(__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php');

class SimpleTest extends TestCase
{
    // use TestCaseTrait;

    protected function getConnection() {}
    protected function getDataSet() {}

    public function testFirstExample()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    public function testSecondExample()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 0);
    }

}
?>

$ phpunit --testdox --verbose --configuration=tests/phpunit.xml tests/SimpleTest.php 
PHPUnit 6.0.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Configuration: /home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/phpunit.xml

Simple
 [x] First example
 [ ] Second example
```

Everything fine and works as expected until I uncomment the line `use TestCaseTrait;`. Since this moment, the tests don't work.
They even don't executed (I checked it by adding next code: `fwrite(STDERR, 'Here we are!')`) inside the test-functions.

The question: what is wrong with `use TestCaseTrait;` statement? Why does it broke the whole test? How can I solve it?

Thank you!
P.S. Sorry for my English.

---

Conclusion:
It is strange, but the problem was in `setUp()` function. You have to add it in the test! When I did it, my test became work properly...

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, yet looking at [phpunit doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html) indicates that  `getConnection` and `getDataSet` should return something. They are void in your example.

Comment: Of course I have tried it. Those functions return
`$this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'test');`
and 
`new MyApp_DbUnit_ArrayDataSet(array(...))`
respectively (as in the documentation). But it isn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

> Conclusion: It is strange, but the problem was in setUp() function.
>   You have to add it in the test! When I did it, my test became work
>   properly

This is not strange, take a look at logs

```
1) SimpleTest::testFirstExample
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\DbUnit\DefaultTester::__construct() must be an instance of PHPUnit\DbUnit\Database\Connection, null given, called in /x/vendor/phpunit/dbunit/src/TestCaseTrait.php on line 102

2) SimpleTest::testSecondExample
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\DbUnit\DefaultTester::__construct() must be an instance of PHPUnit\DbUnit\Database\Connection, null given, called in /x/vendor/phpunit/dbunit/src/TestCaseTrait.php on line 102
```

And what about this line?

```
# TestCaseTrait::102
return new DefaultTester($this->getConnection());
```

Result of `$this->getConnection()` is `null` because you've implemented `getConnection` method as `protected function getConnection() {}`.

By declaring `setUp` you just overrided `TestCaseTrait::setUp` that invokes `$this->getConnection()`, that's why it's working now.

Comment: That's right. Tell me please, how did you get these logs? They are very helpful in problems solving.

Comment: @GHopper I've executed tests with a command line and these errors were on output. How do you execute ur tests?

Comment: `$ phpunit --testdox --verbose --configuration=tests/phpunit.xml tests/SimpleTest.php`